# Chatbookaction: Rate Limit Reached

Tags: chatai

I am using Mathematica 13.3.1.0 and when I try using a chat enabled notebook I receive an error message (Windows 10)
[WarningSign] An unexpected error occurred.

Failure[[WarningSign]  Message:    Rate limit reached for requests. Please try again later.
Tag:    ChatbookAction::RateLimitReached]
What do I need to do?
Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I am trying to use Chatai in Mathematica for the first time.  Outside of Mathematica, I have used ChatGPT about 10 times over the last 2 months.  So hardly at all.  I don't know what I need to do to use ChatGPT in Mathematica.  I have a ChatGPT free account.

Comment: @Paul You need to register for an OpenAI API plan, create an API key and setup the API key into your Mathematica installation. See also: https://support.wolfram.com/62525